# Dygraph how to always show values in the legend

Tags: javascript, legend, dygraphs

Is it possible to always show the values of the signals in the legend even when the mouse is not over the figure?

I think values appearing and disappearing when the mouse is not over the figure are a bit annoying and I would like to come up with a solution which:

- Until the user goes over the figure with the mouse, the legend shows signal names and their values at `x = 0`
- While the user moves the mouse on the figure the legend should work as usual (i.e. being interactive)
- When the mouse is no longer over the figure the legend shows last values pointed

Would it be possible to get something like this? If yes, how?

EDIT: I found out there are callbacks sensitive to mouse events. In particular, `highlightCallback` and `unhighlightCallback` may be used to obtain what I want. Unfortunately, I do not find any example that shows how to change what's shown in the legend, I've only found examples which add HTML below the figure, like in this [callback example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/callback.html).

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the legend reflect the current selection. If there's no selection, there will be no numbers. So try calling `setSelection` in `unhighlightCallback`.

Alternatively, use the new [`legendFormatter`](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683) option. (Until v2 is released, this will require you to build dygraphs from `HEAD`.)

Comment: Why not adding it as a feature? Just put an additional parameter which tells whether to always show numbers (for example in the way I would like them to appear) or only when mouse is over the plot.